# Short-stroke, high-force solenoid design for remote trigger latch design

Tags: solenoid

[image][image][image][image][image]I am looking for a good resource on solenoid design considerations. Moreso leaning to the basics of why what features do what, to further my prototyping on a project.

I am looking to design/manufacture a short stroke/high force linear solenoid to provide remote activation of a spring-loaded pin latch. I am a 20-year seasoned machinist/millwright, but weak in the electrical area and hope you can provide some advice. Professional manufacturing facilities are at my disposal for prototyping. I have produced several prototypes so far that are somewhat adequate but unrefined. My hope is refinements would lead to higher excess force to provide redundant safety factor while ideally reducing overall footprint.

Design constraints:

- intermittent duty, 7 seconds max "on" every hour
- 70 °C operating environment (engine bay)
- 12 V and 24 V power sources to be used (if one solenoid is not able to do this I can make 2 variations with different windings)
- 350+ N of pulling force @ 0.25" stroke
- 1.375" outer diameter preferred, larger is acceptable if need be.
- minimal housing length, but there are no physical constraints
- 5 lb return spring

This type of thing is new to me so pardon my inexperience. i find it a struggle to even know what to ask.

I have been playing with tubular-style solenoids for McMaster-Carr and of my own design, for example, [this one.](https://www.mcmaster.com/69905K117/)
but I think I may need to consider a design more similar to [this one.](https://www.mcmaster.com/6873K5/)

Note: if you know of a commercially available option I may consider it, but I hope to have custom fitment to the device so that may be hard. Perhaps just buying the coils and plunger would be an option when production scale grows. being low volume though i really like keeping manufacturing in house.

Questions I have include:

1. How does wire diameter effect pull force?
2. How does housing material selection effect pull force (outer shell steel vs aluminum)?
3. How does plunger diameter effect pull force?
4. How does plunger face angle (or flat) effect pull force? (see photos)
5. the large solenoid in the photo has huge pulling force, is that doe to the coil/diameter being do big, or the bif flat face of the plundger being pulled? or the opposing taper end from the other samples seen? diameter aside ist length is desirable, if i could scale it down in diameter a bit. compact is important in my application.

...and anything else I don't know to ask!

Comment: Since you are a machinist, you may want to provide a detailed diagram. The pictures at McMaster are external, not a cut-away so far as I looked anyway. And there are several different kinds of "solenoid" arrangements (for example, one with the movable plunger rod already largely inside the solenoid but with a spring and backplate and another with a solenoid with a fixed core rod that doesn't move with an external gap related to another part that moves when activated.) A detailed diagram would help avoid others wondering between several different sets of implementation details.

Comment: ill draw some examples today, thanks!

Comment: I have made edits to the original post and incuded photos of cad and samples i made or bought. im sure i dont even know the questions to ask, but im willing ot beat my head againt the lathe until i get a design that satisfys me, i just need to better understand what does what in broad terms, and what changed can be made to make changes

Comment: That's nice help! I've read papers that do nothing more than apply theory to exploring such "minor" details as the way that each coil layer is wound on top of the prior layer, which does make a significant difference in the resulting solenoid. And also that "Finite Element Method Magnetics" (FEMM) is often used in cases like this. Experience and detail goes into designing and adjusting to create an efficient system. Other than asking you for the diagrams (which clarify things a lot) this is beyond my ability. I've no experience designing these into specifics. Hopefully, someone here does.